# Is it possible to access static methods of a static class without knowing the name of the static class

Tags: c#

I'm just curious about this.. let's say i have N number of static classes that look exactly like the following besides the class name (let's pretend we have Bank1, Bank2, ... , BankN as class names)

```
static class Bank1{
   private static List<string> customers = new List<string>();

   static List<string> getCustomers(){
      return customers;
   }
```

Is it then possible to have a method that can access the getCustomers() method of each Bank class without knowing the name of the class? So for example

```
void printCustomers(string s)
{ 
  *.getCustomers();
  //for-loop to print contents of customers List
}
```

Where * stands for the class name which is passed in the string argument (doesn't have to be a string). Is there a way to do this without using something like

```
if(s.equals("Bank1")) {Bank1.getCustomers();}
else if (s.equals("Bank2")) {Bank2.getCustomers();}
```

etc?

Comment: You can use reflection, but a `switch` like you propose may be faster. Is speed an issue?

Comment: No it's just something that popped into my head

Comment: how would you use reflection to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use reflection for this:

```
// s is a qualified type name, like "BankNamespace.Bank1"
var customers = (List<string>)
        Type.GetType(s).InvokeMember("getCustomers",
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, // assume method is public
             null, null, null);
```

Comment: I guess it's probably a better idea to have a regular class and create an instance of it instead of using static classes in this way isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's a much better idea to use regular classes.

Answer (score -2):

If the class is known statically, you can use generics:

```
void printCustomers<T>()
{
    T.getCustomers();
    ...
}
```

If the class is not known statically, then the natural solution is to use virtual methods (polymorphism), because that's the way to resolve methods at runtime.

Comment: -1 This will not work.  You cannot use a generic to call a static method.

Comment: You're right... I'd remove it but I don't have the rep points.

Comment: I can delete my answers and you have more rep than me.